# Displaying .jpg image when button is clicked in Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

This seems like a pretty straightforward question, but i am having trouble displaying a jpg image when a button is clicked.  Here is my code (without the button code for the sake of time):

```
from tkinter import *

#screen stuff here

canvas = Canvas(app)
canvas.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
photo = PhotoImage(file = "test.jpg")
canvas.create_image(0,0, image = photo)


def show_image():
    global canvas
    global photo
    canvas.create_image(0,0, image = photo)

#button that calls the function down here
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works with Python2:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ImageTk

def show_image():
    x = canvas.create_image(125, 125, image=tk_img)
    while True:
        print('show')
        canvas.itemconfigure(x, state=tk.NORMAL)
        button.configure(text = 'Hide')
        yield
        print('hide')        
        canvas.itemconfigure(x, state=tk.HIDDEN)
        button.configure(text = 'Show')        
        yield

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='image.png')

button = tk.Button(
    root, text="Show", command=show_image().next, anchor='w',
    width=10, activebackground="#33B5E5")
button.grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

In Python3, `PhotoImage` [can open GIF, PPM/PGM images](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#images). To open other formats, you may [need to install Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0) (a fork of the PIL project for Python3).

Comment: I still get teh same error... hmmm.  Are there any other ways to show an image?